# iOS Firebase Authentication with a different project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase in my iOS app for analytics, cloud messaging... and everything is working properly. Now I need to link the app to a different Firebase project to do Firebase authentication. This project is the Firebase project created on Google Cloud when setting up Google Cloud Identity platform. I followed the Firebase guide that explains how to [configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

In `AppDelegate` I've the following code to configure the 2 projects:

```
//Configure default project
FirebaseApp.configure()
            
//Configure project for authentication
let plist = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-auth", ofType: "plist")
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plist!)
FirebaseApp.configure(name: "auth", options: options!)
```

Default `GoogleService-Info.plist` and `GoogleService-Info-auth.plist` are present in the XCode project. Then in a view controller, I first load the second app:

```
let app = FirebaseApp.app(name: "auth")
```

and then create the auth object:

```
let auth = Auth.auth(app: app)
```

If look at `auth` in the debugger, I see that `auth.app` is correctly configured and link to the second project. But, when I do:

```
provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "providerID")
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
      if error != nil {
        // Handle error.
      }
      if credential != nil {
        auth.signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
          if error != nil {
            // Handle error.
          }
          // User is signed in.
        }
      }
    }
```

I get the error that I haven't registered the custom URL scheme in the `Info.plist`. But this scheme corresponds to the default project and not the one I asked to use. I assumed that maybe it is a wrong check of the library and also defined the custom url scheme for the default project but then I get the following error:

```
[auth/operation-not-allowed] - Use of this method requires GCIP. For more information, see the [Firebase API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.OAuthProvider)
```

It tells me that the OAuth provider is not configured. I did not configured anything on the default project so this is correct but I want that the sign-in takes the second one and I think the library is not doing it.

Firebase authentication works correctly if I only configure the second project in the app so I assume that there is an issue with setting-up a different app/project for Firebase authentication only.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "providerID", auth: auth)` fixes the issue. The `OAuthProvider` also need to be configured with the second project.